# Can all players access the DLC levels?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

The [DLC levels](http://store.steampowered.com/dlc/235540) (Schluesselschloss, Drachenfels, Karak Azgaraz, Stromdorf, Death on the Reik)  can be accessed when invited by a Steam friend who owns the DLC (I have no experience with the console versions). I have recently seen many online posts claiming that ownership is only required for hosting.

Can solo players with only the base game play on the DLC maps? Do all lobbies show in the server browser? If not, what happens to vanilla-players when the server changes to a DLC map?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No

Long answer:

- Vermintide doesn't use dedicated servers
- The person who created a lobby (aka the host) is the only person who can select the mission
- The host can only select missions that they own at difficulties that they have unlocked

If you're playing solo, you're the host and as such you can only select missions that you own.  If you're viewing the lobby browser, you're just seeing games that another person is already hosting.

Comment: What happens to players in the lobby with no paid map packs when the host selects a DLC level?

Comment: @user198350 That works just fine.  As you previously mentioned, only the host needs to own the DLC.  The only real catch is that you can't pick up contracts from the contract board for DLC you don't own... and since contract quests have some of the best loot in the game on them...

Comment: In case I misunderstood what you're asking: If the host doesn't own a DLC pack, clicking on that DLC pack in the mission select screen should prompt them to buy it instead of show its missions (although I haven't tried it recently to check).